# Trouble customizing infoWIndow on gmap.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I found a tutorial to how customize your infowindow using google map, well I'm using the library gmap.js so its a little bit different at least for me because sometimes I have to overwrite the code.  I made it but the problem is when you click for the first time on a marker the design looks 'horrible' then when you click another marker the design appears like it should be. I don't know what happens with the first click.

If you are interested in to see the tutorial: 
http://en.marnoto.com/2014/09/5-formas-de-personalizar-infowindow.html

```js
var lat = 18.47695116317757;
var lng = -69.82995986938477;
var zoom = 13;
//Cargar mapa
$(document).ready(function(){
  var map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    lat: lat,
    lng: lng,
    zoom: zoom,
    zoomControl : true,
    zoomControlOpt: {
      style : "SMALL",
      position: "TOP_LEFT"
    },
    panControl : true,
    streetViewControl : false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: false
});

//Cargar marcas
      aparecerMarcas(18.49021274113021,-69.86058533191681,'title','2016-03-02 02:40:28','Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue pop','',1,0);
      aparecerMarcas(18.47695116317757,-69.82995986938477,'los title','2016-03-02 02:41:02','Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue pop','',2,300);

  //Fin

  function aparecerMarcas(latitud,longitud,titulo,fecha,descripcion,imagen,id,tiempo){
    setTimeout(function(){
      var mapa = map.addMarker({
        lat: latitud,
        lng: longitud,
        title: titulo, 
        animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        click: function(){
          //Inicio customizar infowindows
            var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');
            var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();
            iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)').css({'display' : 'none'});
            iwBackground.children(':nth-child(4)').css({'display' : 'none'}); 
            var iwCloseBtn = iwOuter.next();
            iwCloseBtn.css({opacity: '1', right: '38px', top: '3px', border: '7px solid #48b5e9', 'border-radius': '13px', 'box-shadow': '0 0 5px #3990B9'});
            if($('.iw-content').height() < 140){
              $('.iw-bottom-gradient').css({display: 'none'});
            }
            iwCloseBtn.mouseout(function(){
              $(this).css({opacity: '1'});
            });         
          //Fin cutomizar infowindow
        },
        infoWindow: {
          content: '<div id="iw-container">' +
                    '<div class="iw-title">'+titulo+'</div>' +
                    '<div class="iw-content">' +
                      '<div class="iw-subTitle">'+fecha+'</div>' +
                      '<img src=images/'+imagen+' alt='+titulo+' height="115" width="83">' +
                      '<p>'+descripcion+'</p>' +
                      '<div class="iw-subTitle"><a href=info.php>Leer Mas</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="iw-bottom-gradient"></div>' +
                  '</div>',
          maxWidth: 350
        }
      })    
    //console.log(mapa['infoWindow']);
    //

    },tiempo);
  }
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map.map, 'domready', function(){
            map.removeMarkers();
          });
//Fin
});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
html{
  height: 100%;
  }
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
#map {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 400px;
  max-width: none;
  }
#map img {
  max-width: none !important;
  }
.gm-style-iw {
  width: 350px !important;
  top: 15px !important;
  left: 0px !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(178, 178, 178, 0.6);
  border: 1px solid rgba(72, 181, 233, 0.6);
  border-radius: 2px 2px 10px 10px;
  }
#iw-container {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
#iw-container .iw-title {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #48b5e9;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
  }
#iw-container .iw-content {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-right: 1px;
  padding: 15px 5px 20px 15px;
  max-height: 140px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  }
.iw-content img {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 10px; 
  }
.iw-subTitle {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 5px 0;
  }
.iw-bottom-gradient {
  position: absolute;
  width: 326px;
  height: 25px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 18px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GMaps.js Document HTML</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gmaps.js/0.4.22/gmaps.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:500px; opacity: 1;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The infowindow looks the same to me on the first and second clicks in your code snippet.  Are you talking about the "close" X on the top right?

Comment: You have to wait for the infowindow "domready" event before you can manipulate its DOM.

Comment: yeah but i dont know how o where add the domready i was trying to google.maps.event.addlistener(AneedAddAvariable,'domready',function) but which if in the tutorial he use infowindow but my infowindow is inside addmarkers like property... when you mean the same are you meaning it look good or look like out of size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait for the infowindow "domready" event before you can manipulate its DOM.  Looking at the source for [GMaps.js](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/), the marker's infoWindow is `marker.infoWindow`.

[source](https://github.com/hpneo/gmaps/blob/master/lib/gmaps.markers.js) line 26:     `marker.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options.infoWindow);`

So this should work:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(mapa.infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
//Inicio customizar infowindows
  var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');
  var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();
  iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)').css({'display' : 'none'});
  iwBackground.children(':nth-child(4)').css({'display' : 'none'}); 
  var iwCloseBtn = iwOuter.next();
  iwCloseBtn.css({opacity: '1', right: '38px', top: '3px', border: '7px solid #48b5e9', 'border-radius': '13px', 'box-shadow': '0 0 5px #3990B9'});
  if($('.iw-content').height() < 140){
    $('.iw-bottom-gradient').css({display: 'none'});
  }
  iwCloseBtn.mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css({opacity: '1'});
  });         
//Fin cutomizar infowindow
});
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var lat = 18.47695116317757;
var lng = -69.82995986938477;
var zoom = 13;
//Cargar mapa
$(document).ready(function(){
  var map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    lat: lat,
    lng: lng,
    zoom: zoom,
    zoomControl : true,
    zoomControlOpt: {
      style : "SMALL",
      position: "TOP_LEFT"
    },
    panControl : true,
    streetViewControl : false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: false
});

//Cargar marcas
      aparecerMarcas(18.49021274113021,-69.86058533191681,'title','2016-03-02 02:40:28','Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue pop','',1,0);
      aparecerMarcas(18.47695116317757,-69.82995986938477,'los title','2016-03-02 02:41:02','Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue pop','',2,300);

  //Fin

  function aparecerMarcas(latitud,longitud,titulo,fecha,descripcion,imagen,id,tiempo){
    setTimeout(function(){
      var mapa = map.addMarker({
        lat: latitud,
        lng: longitud,
        title: titulo, 
        animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        infoWindow: {
          content: '<div id="iw-container">' +
                    '<div class="iw-title">'+titulo+'</div>' +
                    '<div class="iw-content">' +
                      '<div class="iw-subTitle">'+fecha+'</div>' +
                      '<img src=images/'+imagen+' alt='+titulo+' height="115" width="83">' +
                      '<p>'+descripcion+'</p>' +
                      '<div class="iw-subTitle"><a href=info.php>Leer Mas</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="iw-bottom-gradient"></div>' +
                  '</div>',
          maxWidth: 350
        }
      });    
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(mapa.infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
                //Inicio customizar infowindows
            var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');
            var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();
            iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)').css({'display' : 'none'});
            iwBackground.children(':nth-child(4)').css({'display' : 'none'}); 
            var iwCloseBtn = iwOuter.next();
            iwCloseBtn.css({opacity: '1', right: '38px', top: '3px', border: '7px solid #48b5e9', 'border-radius': '13px', 'box-shadow': '0 0 5px #3990B9'});
            if($('.iw-content').height() < 140){
              $('.iw-bottom-gradient').css({display: 'none'});
            }
            iwCloseBtn.mouseout(function(){
              $(this).css({opacity: '1'});
            });         
          //Fin cutomizar infowindow
      });
    },tiempo);
  }
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map.map, 'domready', function(){
            map.removeMarkers();
          });
//Fin
});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
html{
  height: 100%;
  }
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
#map {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 400px;
  max-width: none;
  }
#map img {
  max-width: none !important;
  }
.gm-style-iw {
  width: 350px !important;
  top: 15px !important;
  left: 0px !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(178, 178, 178, 0.6);
  border: 1px solid rgba(72, 181, 233, 0.6);
  border-radius: 2px 2px 10px 10px;
  }
#iw-container {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
#iw-container .iw-title {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #48b5e9;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
  }
#iw-container .iw-content {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-right: 1px;
  padding: 15px 5px 20px 15px;
  max-height: 140px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  }
.iw-content img {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 10px; 
  }
.iw-subTitle {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 5px 0;
  }
.iw-bottom-gradient {
  position: absolute;
  width: 326px;
  height: 25px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 18px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GMaps.js Document HTML</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gmaps.js/0.4.22/gmaps.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:500px; opacity: 1;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: NO wayyyyyyyy i wrote that but at this way google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(mapa['infoWindow'], 'domready', function(), uffff wow thanks you... like bryan said in taken "i will find you and i will pay you"... thaaanks you

Comment: I had to use addListener in place of addListenerOnce as my markers were dynamically generated from a json source.
I was facing a lot of troubles in configuring info-windows with gmaps.js and this solution really helped me